# Powershell execute script again, no closing powershell windows when "Run with powershell"

Tags: powershell

I have a script powershell, and I run it with "Execute with powershell".
My script launch, do its things and close the windows.
Can I have my script not closing the windows and repeat the script without closing the powershell window?
I have created a .bat with "PowerShell -NoExit "C:\Temp\Scripts\wclonex.ps1" but the powershell script close after.

Thanks for the answers.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the entirety of the script to run over and over again you can encapsulate it in a loop.

This is not good practice as you pretty much always want a terminating condition on a loop.
In this case get-service would just be the entire script

For example

```
while($true){get-service}
```

If you want the Powershell Window to stay open at the end of the script and not close you can add the "Pause" command at the end.

What are you trying to accomplish with the script? There might be a better way to go about it.